# Nested If function In excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

This one works well

```
=IF(OFFSET(D17;0;-1)<>0;C17*($L$6/$D$7)(V17+273,15)/($F$7+273,15);IF(OFFSET(D17;0;-2)<>0;B17($L$6/470)*(V17+273,15)/(850+273,15);IF(AND($H$7="V";$J$7="V";A17="GPFc_Essence");AD17;N17))
```

need some help with this nested if function somehow it doesn't accept any other options when i add two more conditions

```
=IF(OFFSET(D17;0;-1)<>0;C17*($L$6/$D$7)(V17+273,15)/($F$7+273,15);IF(OFFSET(D17;0;-2)<>0;B17($L$6/470)*(V17+273,15)/(850+273,15);IF(AND($H$7="V";$J$7="V";A17="GPFc_Essence");AD17;IF(AND($H$7="V";$J$7="N");AA17;IF(AND($H$7="N";$J$7="V";);AC17;N17)))))
```

returns either complete false N17 or value for $H$7="V";$J$7="V"; i want to add possible combinations can anyone suggest the best way to do so?

thank you in advance

Comment: Your first formula is missing a closed bracket at the end)

Comment: I do not think I understand the purpose. Why would you ever want such long formula in a cell? And have hard-coded numbers in there? In a year, it will be impossible for you to recollect what you did. My advice is to split it up in cells.

Comment: The nesting is done properly in terms of there are only two choices for each IF, and the second formula has the right number of brackets.

Comment: you have an extra ; at the end of your very last END condition.  Right after the "v"

Comment: Your formulae are also missing multiplication signs `*` between parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple typos in your formula including missing *, extra commas and missing brackets. Once reviewed the formula to be grammatically correct should be as follows:

```
=IF(C17<>0;C17*($L$6/$D$7)*(V17+273,15)/($F$7+273,15);IF(B17<>0;B17*($L$6/470)*(V17+273,15)/(850+273,15);IF(AND($H$7="V";$J$7="V";A17="GPFc_Essence");AD17;IF(AND($H$7="V";$J$7="N");AA17;IF(AND($H$7="N";$J$7="V");AC17;N17)))))
```

If you are using comma as separator and american notation for values, then the formula would be:

```
=IF(C17<>0,C17*($L$6/$D$7)*(V17+273.15)/($F$7+273.15),IF(B17<>0,B17*($L$6/470)*(V17+273.15)/(850+273.15),IF(AND($H$7="V",$J$7="V",A17="GPFc_Essence"),AD17,IF(AND($H$7="V",$J$7="N"),AA17,IF(AND($H$7="N",$J$7="V"),AC17,N17)))))
```

If you end up with a lot of values to check against one cell, I'd suggest to create a helper table with the values to compare of.

Comment: thank you so much kaiser ,       i tried shortening the conditions even this with three if's doesn't execute well =IF(AND($H$7="V";$J$7="V";A17="GPFc_Essence");AD17;IF(AND($H$7="V";$J$7="N");AA17;IF(AND($H$7="N";$J$7="V");AC17;N17))), i don't understand why it provides only the first true condition ;or its false ; the two loops within first if loop extended as  false condition don't work at all  my objective is too select right value from the cells AA17, AC17 and AD17 depending upon the values used in H7 and J7  3  combinations 3 values  thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data?

Comment: You shouldn't be providing your email here. If the data can't be provided, please provide some test data (sample data) to see what you want to do.

Comment: i found a solution !!!!! so happy slight mistake was there as in my if condition for false "F" was denoted instead of "N" french English translation issue completely , it works well so happy